# Splitting number and string using linq

Tags: c#, split

I have a string which its first part is a string and last one is a number, like this:

ahde7394

so what I would like to obtain is:

ahde

7394

I have thought to first extract the string and then from the last position of the character obtain the number until the end of the string so I think using indexers can be done somehow:

```
var stringQuery = NameComp.Select((str,index) => new {myStr=str, position=index})
                                               .Where(c => !Char.IsDigit(c.myStr)).Select((ch,pos) => new { newStr=ch, pos=pos} );
```

then I could do:

1) To obtain the string: stringQuery.newStr

2) To obtain the number: stringQuery.Skip(stringQuery.pos).Select(d => d);

but it is not working, after obtaining stringQuery I cannot access to its items as it is an anonymous type....

Any ideas?

**Solution using LINQ**, guessing that str="ahde7394":

```
string letters = new string(str.TakeWhile(c => Char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
```

and for number:

```
string number = new string(str.Skip(letters.Length).TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c)).ToArray());
```

or better guessing last part is a number:

```
   string number = str.Substring(name.Length);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agree with dtb that LINQ is probably not the right solution.

Regex is another option, assuming that your string can be much more variable than you have provided.

```
var str = "ahde7394";

var regex = Regex.Match(str, @"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)");

var letters = regex.Groups[1].Value; // ahde
var numbers = regex.Groups[2].Value; // 7394
```

Comment: This is a very nice solution. Anyway using Linq also could be done. See my updated post. I am wondering which is more efficient and faster in this case... anyone knows?

Comment: Performance in this specific instance and with these specific sizes would be unnoticeable.

Comment: and for large strings? (I know this is out of the scope of this thread but It is good to know that)

Comment: They would have to be gigantic strings. As they move towards gigantic.. you would probably find that this Regex version would become the slower of the two.

Answer (score 2):

LINQ might not be the best solution here. Have a look at the [String.IndexOfAny Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11w09h50.aspx):

```
char[] digits = new[] { '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9' };

string input = "ahde7394";

int index = input.IndexOfAny(digits);

string head = input.Substring(0, index);  // "ahde"
string tail = input.Substring(index);     // "7394"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.IndexOf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.indexof.aspx) and [`String.Substring`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.substring.aspx) like;

```
string s = "ahde7394";
int index = 0;
foreach (var i in s)
{
     if(Char.IsDigit(i))
     {
        index = s.IndexOf(i);
        break;
     }
}

Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(0, index));
Console.WriteLine(s.Substring(index));
```

Output will be;

```
ahde
7394
```

Here a <kbd>[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/GxbKUb)</kbd>.